# Python - error in drawing contour plot using scipy.integrate.quad

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, contour

I am trying to draw a contour plot in Python, using a slightly more complicated code than the below. But, the same problem arises in the following simple example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def A(x):
    return integrate.quad(lambda i: x-i, 0, x)

n = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, n)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
M = A(X) + Y  # THE ERROR ARISES HERE

plt.contour(X, Y, M)
plt.show()
```

The following error message is shown at the line indicated above:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I want to use `integrate.quad()`.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two problems: (1) by default, `quad` returns *two* values (see the [docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html)); (2) the integration limits must be scalars, not arrays.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Mr.T What I was looking for was a figure like the one in the answer of ImportanceOfBeingEarnest. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @WarrenWeckesser pointed out correctly in the comments, the two problems are

- [`quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) returns a tuple, from which you would only need the first member here.
- The integral you want to compute is scalar, so you cannot pass a 2D array to it.

The solutions:

- index the return of `quad`: `quad( ..., )[0]` to take only the first item out
- [`vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) the call to `A`, such that it gets called with all the scalars of the array `X` one by one. Note that this is not very efficient, but should be fine with an array of 100x100 elements as presented here.

A complete solution would look like

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def A(x):
    return integrate.quad(lambda i: x-i, 0, x)[0]

n = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, n)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
M = np.vectorize(A)(X) + Y

plt.contour(X, Y, M)
plt.show()
```

[image]